# Disable jni logging on Android production version

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface, android-log

I created a logger.h file and I include and use it on my c++ code:

```
#ifndef LOG_TAG
#define  LOG_TAG    "jni"
#include <android/log.h>
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#endif // LOG_TAG
```

In my java application file I use the following code to detect debug mode:

```
private boolean inDebugMode() {
    boolean inDebugMode = false;
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        int flags = packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags;
        inDebugMode = (flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // GlobalData.DEBUG_MODE = inDebugMode;
    return inDebugMode;
}
```

How can I do it on the native code?

Code examples would be appreciated...

Comment: Doesn't `#ifdef DEBUG/#ifdef NDEBUG` work for you?

Comment: It does, but I would prefer to do it automatically on runtime, or at least to change it in a single place - on the java side

Comment: Have you tried using JNI to call a Java method from C++?  You can just call your `inDebugMode()` method from **logger.cpp** class.